# How to INSERT - WHERE NOT EXISTS on another table with a matching column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking for a SQL statement that would read similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO some_table
  (a, b, c)
VALUES
  ('a', 'b', 'c')
RETURNING
   a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT
    some_column
  FROM
    another_table
  WHERE
    some_cond='is_true'
);
```

Above wouldn't work as `WHERE NOT EXISTS` is to be followed by `SELECT FROM` not `INSERT INTO`. How can I insert into a table only when a select statement on another table returns nothing?

EDIT2:

Changed database schema to contain a matching column on other table and not null constrain on matched 'to-be-inserted-into' column to use sub-query with select to get the intended functionality and use what @Isaiah3015 suggested.

Comment: Also see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591392/mysql-insert-if-value-not-exist-in-another-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to create an INSERT sytanx with what you want to SELECT

```
INSERT INTO table ( column1, column2, column 3, etc)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, etc from table where condition = 'whatever 
condition you want inserted into the table'
```

Comment: Two tables are different for my case, they have no matching columns.

Comment: If they don't have any matching data at all how do you determine the NOT IN or NOT EXIST? Then your first table would just the SELECT INTO. There's no need of NOT EXIST.

Comment: Assuming `SELECT INTO` is there to copy data from one table into another, I don't need that functionality. I am not sure what you meant by - how to determine..

Comment: The purpose of NOT EXIST is to exclude or include specific data (depending on how you look at it). For ex: Table1 has ID 1,2,3,4,5,6 and table2 has ID of 1,2,3. If you write INSERT INTO table () Select ID FROM Table1 where ID NOT EXIST / NOT IN( Select ID from table2), the values that will be inserted are **4,5,6**. Because these are the values that **does not exist** in Table2. If you have no correlation between Table1 and 2 (like you said), how do you determine what to exclude?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO some_table(a, b, c)
    SELECT 'a', 'b', 'c'
    FROM dual
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT some_column
                      FROM another_table
                      WHERE some_cond = 'is_true'
                     )
RETURNING a;
```

Comment: Table 'Dual' does not have 'a', 'b', 'c' in them for my case. They are different tables without any matching columns.

Comment: @RobertC.Holland . . . `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'` are constant strings in your question and they are constant strings in this answer.  This has nothing to do with the columns in `dual`.